# Change Template with Button without code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've a XAML Code with a Listview. Now I want to change the CellTemplate with a button
but without code behind. How can I do this?

Templates:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="URL"  >
  <TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding XPath=@URL}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@URL}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
  </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Text">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@URL}"/>
</DataTemplate>    


<Grid>  
<Grid.Resources>
  <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data">
    <x:XData>
      <Data xmlns="">
        <Item ID="1" Desc="Google" URL="http://www.google.com" Acceptable="true"/>
        <Item ID="2" Desc="StackOverflow" URL="http://www.stackoverflow.com" Acceptable="true"/>
        <Item ID="3" Desc="4chan" URL="http://www.4chan.org" Acceptable="false"/>
      </Data>
    </x:XData>
  </XmlDataProvider>
</Grid.Resources>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Here is the button where magic should happen and set the CellTemplate from URLColumn.
I want to have Text as CellTemplate when I click on this button.

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" 
  Name="Text"
  Content="Text"/>
```

Listview with the GridViewColumn URLColumn. I want to change it's CellTemplate.

```
<ListView 
  Grid.Column="1"
  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}, XPath=/Data}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@Desc}"/>
      <GridViewColumn x:Key="URLColumn" Header="URL" CellTemplate="{StaticResource URL}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Acceptable">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding XPath=@Acceptable}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

Is this without code behind possible? If so, how? 
I've already search the internet the whole day, but couldn't find an anwser.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install Expression Blend Interactivity NuGet package (or add reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll` from Expression Blend SDK manually):

```
Install-Package Blend.Interactivity.Wpf
```

Then use `ChangePropertyAction` trigger action:

```
<Button
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" Grid.Column="0" Name="Text" Content="Text">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="URLColumn" PropertyName="CellTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Text}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```